# is there a method to take screenshots of telegram chat?(want to make a telegram chat screenshot taker)

Tags: python-3.x, screenshot, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am currently writing a bot to take screenshots of Telegram chat in Python.
I have written the options the bot is supposed to give to the user when it's started but I have no idea how to do this.

is it possible at all?

does telegram even let us do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on official [Documents of Telegram](https://telegram.org/faq#q-are-bots-safe) :

> Bots are no different from human users that you meet in groups for example. They can see your public name, username, and profile pictures, and they can see messages you send to them, that's it.

and you can find more information from [bots-privacy-mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode)

so basically Telegram doesn't let BOTs do such things as taking screenshots.